# Bokeh: Using CustomJS opens new window

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I'd like to leverage Bokeh's rich and excellent library to create plots that allows a user to select groups for plotting data within Jupyter Notebook.

I have followed the following tutorial:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/slider.html

However, when combining this tutorial with the "output_notebook" module, the plots are handled both within the notebook and in a new window. I have isolated the problem to the CustomJS module, probably the callback method.

How do I toggle off plotting in a new window?

I have followed the tutorial and made the following changes:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
output_notebook()
```

and in show:

```
show(layout, notebook_handle=True)
```

Comment: answered my own question.

I installed flexx with: `pip install flexx`, handled the show plot function as above and followed the guide in this [link](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#userguide-interaction-actions-widget-callbacks)

Comment: You can get your plot in html file and can see it in browser. for that `from bokeh.plotting import output_file` and before the `show()` command just write `output_file("Graph.html")`

Comment: I don't want the browser to open a new window, nor an output file. I want the displays in Jupyter only.

Comment: I can guarantee there is nothing about `CustomJS` to do with this. I have also tried the linked example in a notebook and it functions as expected (no separate windows, only notebook output). You have almost certainly still called `output_file` somewhere inadvertently. Note that `output_file` is *persistent* so you'd need to restart the kernel or call `reset_output` to turn it off, not just re-execute cells without it present. Otherwise, not much more can be said without seeing your complete code.

Comment: Nice one bigreddot. I've just tried it and you're correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Writing as an answer so the information is more prominent)

The `output_file` command initiates a *persistent* operational mode. *All* subsequent `show` commands will result in the specified file being created (or overwritten). Merely deleting a notebook cell with `output_file` will not turn this mode off. You must either:

- explicitly call `reset_output` to cancel, or
- restart the notebook kernel